# Angular 5 lazy loaded app and browser navigation buttons

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a big app which is mostly created by composing a lot of lazily loaded modules. My problem is with the browser buttons, whether the user clicks on `back`, `forward` or `refresh` my app crashes.

As far as I've researched, I could somehow catch those events, stop them from propagating and handle the event myself.

Are there any other good solutions for this? What aspects should I take into consideration?

***Edit due to comments***

I don't think this would be an angular router issue. Thing is, my app programatically changes the router configuration at runtime. Therefore when an user tries to reload or such, he tries to enter a path not yet existant. I could somehow play with the datastore and re-inject the router config before navigation but I don't think that would be wise.

By crashing, I simply mean errors such as `couldn't find route 'x\a\b'`.

The current idea I have now, is to catch the events of the browser buttons and handle them myself, changing the way they work but I'm not sure whether this would even be possible (something like what gmail does I guess).

Comment: Could you post some of your route configurations

Comment: @IzzoObella Not really, I'm playing with it in the app by programmatically adding/removing routes. It's not really a static configuration but rather a dynamic one.

Comment: I believe it is not angular routing issue. This might be the cause of the server hosting the application. Is it hosted on IIS?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing" exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a tremendous number of routes and to handle route changes i use the routeEvent

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Event, NavigationEnd, NavigationError, NavigationStart, Router} from '@angular/router';
...
  routerEvent;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.routerEvent = router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // Show loading indicator
      }

      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // Hide loading indicator
        this.init();
      }

      if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
        // Hide loading indicator
        // Present error to user
      }
    });
  }
```

As the event names suggest, **NavigationStart** is triggered when you freshly load your route, **NavigationEnd** is triggered when the route navigation load is complete and **NavigationError** when your route fails to load.

It's also a good idea to unsubscribe when nolonger needed.

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.routerEvent.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this would help. I'm talking about a way to handle the events coming from the browser's buttons not from inside my app. Could you explain how I should leverage this to for example, have my app not crash on a `refresh`?

Comment: What processes are you running on refresh that cause it to crash or what exactly do you mean by crash

Comment: @user1640736 i used this for dynamically loading routes, so all logic in onInit was moved to NavigationStart so that for-example on refresh this code is executed.